# List object ToDictionary <object, List<object>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

```
public class User
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string login { get; set; }     
   public string company { get; set; }
}
```

How can I convert `List<User>` to `ToDictionary<string, List<string>>`
where key : `company`  value : names.

I try to do so

```
List<User> users = context.getallUsers();
var usersByCompany = users .ToDictionary<string, List<string>>(u => u.company, users.Where(d=>d.company==u.company).Select(c=>c.name).ToList());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First group users by company, then convert groups to dictionary:

```
users.GroupBy(u => u.company)
     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                   g => g.Select(u => u.name).ToList());
```

Note: Type of dictionary will be inferred from usage.

Also you can consider to use `ILookup<string, string>` instead of `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`:

```
users.ToLookup(u => u.company, u => u.name)
```

Comment: Downvoting means *this answer is not useful*. Downvoter, I would be very thankful if you'll explain why its not useful or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `ToLookup` method:

```
ILookup<string, User> usersLookup = users.ToLookup(u => u.company);
```

`usersLookup` will be indexable by `company`

```
foreach (User u in userLookup["IBM"]) {...} //IBM users
```

if you still need company-name pairs, try following:

```
ILookup<string, string> usersLookup = users.ToLookup(u => u.company, u => u.name);
```

Comment: OP wants list of names, not whole User objects. Also I already mentioned Lookups option

Comment: You've probably edited the answer, in your first version you didn't mention that option.

Comment: Now you are duplicating my solution. Is there any particular reason for that? Also my answer appeared 7 minutes before yours. All edits was complete even earlier.

Comment: Sergey, once I entered this thread, your answer didn't contain `ToLookup` option, so I've added it. You've probably edited your answer when I was posting mine.

Comment: BTW, Don't know why was your answer downvoted, I didn't do that.